# Excel Add-in JS Error: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, compiler-errors, office-js, office-addins

I'm developing Microsoft Excel Add-in JS using Visual Studio, suddenly I got 71 error in "index.t.ds: file while compiling the project.
I tried creating blank project and repairing both Visual Studio and MS Office but I still got the same errors.

Sample of the errors:

Error 1:

> Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file: Succeeded, Failed, Inserted, DocumentOpened, Word, Excel, PowerPoint, Outlook, OneNote, Project, Access, PC, OfficeOnline, Mac, iOS,...

Error 2:

> In an enum with multiple declarations, only one declaration can omit an initializer for its first enum element.

Error 3:

> Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'handler' must be of type 'string', but here has type 'BindingEventHandler'.

Error 4:

> All declarations of 'recurrenceProperties' must have identical modifiers.

Error 5:

> Duplicate number index signature.

Comment: Could you be loading two different versions of the Office JavaScript library? Maybe one from a CDN and one from a local copy?

Comment: I started created new project to avoid such problem but still having the same error.